# Best way to POST/GET data from jQuery to MVC 4 controller and return View

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I have a table with information on a customer, including their name, phone, email, etc. I set up the table to have a radio button to select a customer from this table. This radio-button calls a jQuery function that gets the customer's name from a controller method. I'm looking for the proper and best way to pass both the CustomerID and CustomerName to a CustomerEvent controller which returns a view of events for the specific customer. If I try to use an AJAX POST, it does not return the View in the `data`. I've also tried window.location and that does not work either.

Here's the razor code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Events ", "../CustomerEvent/Index", null, new { id = "btnEventsCustomerID" })
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').val($(this).val());            
        var CustomerID = jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').val();
        var CustomerName = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Customer/GetCustomerName',
            data: { id: CustomerID },
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                CustomerName = data
            }
        });
        alert(CustomerName);
        jQuery('#btnEventsCustomerID').click(function () {
            window.location = "/CustomerEvent/Index/?CustomerID=" + CustomerID + "&CustomerName=" + CustomerName;             
        });
```

The CustomerName alert is functioning properly. 
Here is my controller method for returning a view of Customer events:

```
public ActionResult Index(int CustomerID = 0, string CustomerName="")
    {            
        if (CustomerID != 0)
        {                
            Session["CustomerID"] = CustomerID;               
            Customer CustomerObj = _customer.GetCustomer(CustomerID);
            Session["CustomerName"] = CustomerObj.FirstName + " "+ CustomerObj.LastName;
        }
        return View(_customerEvent.GetCustomerEventCustomList(CustomerID));            
    }
```

Comment: Why do you get `CustomerName` with request instead of storing it in data attrubute of radio?

Comment: How are you binding the data to the table? EF? Using strongly typed view?

Comment: YD1m - How would the radio hold two attributes? curtisk - Using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you sending CustomerName at all? It looks like you don't use it in your controller method since you key off the ID and get the customer details(including name)in the CustomerObj. Simplify if you can and prune that out...

You have effectively two ways to call the same controller method from the same link, one in the action link, which currently passes null to the method, and the .click() override in your jQuery which actually tries to pass the method params, problem is, both are butting heads

Since you are using action link, actually pass route values (where you had null originally), modify as such and you should be good to go (and get rid of jQuery click override since it look like you are effectively moving user to new view):

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Events ", "../CustomerEvent/Index", 
         new{CustomerID = model.CustomerID}, new { id = "btnEventsCustomerID" })
```

just change `model.CustomerID` relative to however you are referencing the model data in your view

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right and that the controller method needs to be changed. I had originally changed it and then changed it back. Thanks!

Comment: you can use t4mvc to give paths instead on ../ to make sure you dont get issue at any case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an editor in front of me, but I'll give it a go.  It sounds like there are a couple of different questions here so I'll try to hit them both.

To store the customername in a data attribute like YD1m suggests, you would do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Events ", "../CustomerEvent/Index", null, new { id = "btnEventsCustomerID, data_customer_name = "customernamehere" })
```

Here's more info on the data attribute: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

As for ajaxically getting your view back from your CustomerEvent controller, what I would do is use jQuery's "load" function.  I would start by making your action return a PartialView (not exactly necessary but I prefer to be precise).  Then, in your client script:

```
jQuery('input[type=radio]').change(function () {

    jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').val($(this).val());            

    var CustomerID = jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').val();
    var CustomerName = jQuery('#hdnCustomerID').attr('data-customer-name');

    $("#SOME_CONTAINER_FOR_THE_VIEW").load('/Customer/GetCustomerName?customerId=' + CustomerID + '&customerName=' + CustomerName, function(){ alert('done')});
```

More on jQuery's .load() function here: http://api.jquery.com/load/